# Не даёт инициализировать массив

Tags: java

Есть код:

```
public class FunDep {
    HashSet<Object> body;
    HashSet<Object> head;

    public FunDep(HashSet<Object> body, HashSet<Object> head) {
        this.head = head;
        this.body = body;
    }
}

public static Object SetSortShapes(mxGraph var2) {

    var2.selectCells(true, true);
    Object[] var3 = var2.getSelectionCells();
    ArrayList<Object> Entity_mas = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> Relation_Mas = new ArrayList<>();
    FunDep[] FunDepMas = new FunDep[200];
    int FunDepMasCount = 0;
    int EntityCounter = 0, RelationCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < var3.length; ++i) {
        if (var2.getModel().isVertex(var3[i]) == true) {
            switch (var2.getModel().getStyle(var3[i])) {
                case "fillColor=#289bfc":
                    Entity_mas.add(EntityCounter, var3[i]);
                    ++EntityCounter;
                    break;

                case "rhombus;fillColor=#fff312":
                    Relation_Mas.add(RelationCounter, var3[i]);
                    ++RelationCounter;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < EntityCounter; ++i) //ищем пары ключевые-неключевые по сущностям
    {
        ArrayList<Object> keyAttr = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Object> NotkeyAttr = new ArrayList<>();
        int keyAttrCount = 0;
        int NotkeyAttrCount = 0;
        Object[] Entity_massiv = Entity_mas.toArray(new Object[Entity_mas.size()]);
        Object[] edges_mass = var2.getEdges(Entity_massiv[i]);
        Object[] vertex_mas = var2.getOpposites(edges_mass, Entity_massiv[i]);

        if (vertex_mas.length > 1) //если кол-во элементов равно единице - зависимостей нет
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < vertex_mas.length; ++k) //закидываем атрибуты во временные массивы
            {
                if (var2.getModel().getStyle(vertex_mas[k]).equals("ellipse;fillColor=#31eb47;fontStyle=4") == true) {
                    keyAttr.add(keyAttrCount, vertex_mas[k]);
                    ++keyAttrCount;

                }

                if (var2.getModel().getStyle(vertex_mas[k]).equals("ellipse;fillColor=#31eb47") == true) {
                    NotkeyAttr.add(NotkeyAttrCount, vertex_mas[k]);
                    ++NotkeyAttrCount;
                }
            }

            if (keyAttrCount >= 1 && NotkeyAttrCount >= 1) {
                Object[] keyAttr_mas = keyAttr.toArray(new Object[keyAttr.size()]);
                Object[] NotkeyAttr_mas = NotkeyAttr.toArray(new Object[NotkeyAttr.size()]);

                for (int a = 0; a < keyAttrCount; ++a) {
                    FunDepMas[FunDepMasCount].head.add(keyAttr_mas[a]);

                    for (int b = 0; b < NotkeyAttrCount; ++b) {
                        FunDepMas[FunDepMasCount].body.add(NotkeyAttr_mas[b]);
                    }
                    ++FunDepMasCount;
                }
            }


        }

    }
    return FunDepMas[0];
  }
}
```

При попытке инициализации элемента массива `FunDepMas` выдаёт ошибку. Подозреваю, что что-то с классом накосячил, только понять не могу, что.

Код ошибки:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mxgraph.examples.swing.editor.Normalize.SetSortShapes(Normalize.java:63)
at com.mxgraph.examples.swing.editor.EditorAboutFrame.<init>(EditorAboutFrame.java:48)
at com.mxgraph.examples.swing.editor.BasicGraphEditor.about(BasicGraphEditor.java:679)
at com.mxgraph.examples.swing.editor.EditorMenuBar$3.actionPerformed(EditorMenuBar.java:170)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:980)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1024)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6578)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3343)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6343)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2259)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4961)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2317)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4793)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4539)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4480)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2303)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2758)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4793)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:711)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:99)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow.

Массив создали, а объекты в нем?

```
FunDep[] FunDepMas = new FunDep[200];
for (int i = 0; i < FunDepMas.length; ++i)
  FunDepMas[i] = new FunDep(new HashSet<Object>(), new HashSet<Object>());

...
```